# Whether Sentinel 3 OLCI can be used as a MODIS replacement for 250m NDVI?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, ndvi, sentinel-3

Based on the bandwidths MODIS bands 1 and 2 (620nm - 876nm) will match S3 bands Oa7 - Oa17 (620nm - 865nm)

I am just trying to know if anyone had any experience in using S3 data instead of MODIS for any image processing?

Comment: Yes. Based on the bandwidths MODIS bands 1 and 2 (620nm - 876nm) will match S3 bands Oa7 - Oa17 (620nm - 865nm)

Comment: Yes, I am still looking if anyone had any experience in using S3 data instead of MODIS for any image processing.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. This will of course work as OLCI has the same bands and MODIS for NDVI.
You will have to apply a suitable cloudmask, however.